# Update record with an external application

Tags: python, odoo

I'm trying to create a record in an external application by sending a http request to that application from odoo.
When the application returns a 200 response, it means that the record has been created, so I want to retrieve that record, but I cannot find it with a search.
I know that the record has been created because if I put a long sleep and I open a new tab on my browser, I can see that record in Odoo, but the search method isn't able to find it.
Any sugestions?

This is an example code of what I'm trying to achieve.
Thanks in advance.

```
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    response = requests.post(url = MY_URL, json = ANY_JSON, headers = MY_HEADERS)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return self.env['my_model'].search([('variable', '=', 
                        values["any_attribute"])], order='id')[-1] # The last one
    raise UserError("Record cannot be created due a server error.")
```

Btw: in the external application, the record is being created directly on the database.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! 
if i understood you well, you have to return super of create function of Models.model in order to complete record creation process so odoo will commit transaction on db, to save your new record you can use many2one field in the current model let's say it's `my_new_record_id`.
So code could be like:

```
my_new_record_id = fields.Many2one('my_model')

@api.model
def create(self, values):
    response = requests.post(url = MY_URL, json = ANY_JSON, headers = MY_HEADERS)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        values['my_new_record_id'] = self.env['my_model'].search([('variable', '=', 
                        values["any_attribute"])], order='id')[-1].id
    else:
        raise UserError("Record cannot be created due a server error.")
    return super(ModelName, self).create(values)
```

i wish this help you